# Swift, XCode 6, add new section to existing uitableview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, xcode6

I have a view in which I have a button at the top and a tableview right beneath it. I am displaying one section by default. What I want to achieve is, when the button is clicked, I want add a whole new section right beneath the default section. I want to keep appending new sections below the existing sections as the button is pressed.

**Before button click:**

Button

```
 <UITableView>
     Default Section Header
       Row 1
       Row 2
       Row 3
</UITableView>
```

**After button press**

Button

```
<UITableView>
  Default Section Header
   Row 1
   Row 2
   Row 3

  Newly added section header
   Row 1
   Row 2
   Row 3
   Row 4
</UITableView>
```

I searched a lot but I only found Objective-C references.

I know I need to use the following functions:

`insertRowsAtIndexPaths` and `insertSections`

but I really can't understand how to use that with Swift. I am new to iOS development.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please comment your code upto what you tried.  upload a image which type output you want if you have?

Answer (score 0):

> i'm just giving you some code.use as reference.

```
class MyInfoView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myInfoTableView: UITableView!

var headerNamesArray: [String]?//= ["Personal Details", "Contact Details","Emergency Contacts", "Dependents", "Immigration", "Job", "Salary", "Report-to", "Qualifications", "Memberships"]
var cellDetailsArray:NSDictionary?
var currentExpandedIndex:Int = -1
var isButtonTapped:Bool = false

//MARK:- Register Tableview Method -
func registerTableView()
{
    println(self.frame)
    myInfoTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - 64)
    myInfoTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "InfoCellID")
    loadTableViewDetails()
}
//MARK:- Loading details from Plist -
func loadTableViewDetails()
{
    cellDetailsArray = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TextFieldNames", ofType: "plist")!)
    headerNamesArray = cellDetailsArray!.allKeys as? [String]
    println(cellDetailsArray)
}
//MARK:- tableview header button Action -
func headerButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
{
    isButtonTapped = !isButtonTapped

    var anIndex:NSInteger = sender.tag
    var indexSet:NSMutableIndexSet = NSMutableIndexSet(index: anIndex)

    if anIndex == currentExpandedIndex {
        //            myInfoTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths( (currentExpandedIndex, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Right);
        currentExpandedIndex = -1
    } else if (currentExpandedIndex != -1 ) {
        indexSet.addIndex(currentExpandedIndex)
        currentExpandedIndex =  anIndex
        isButtonTapped = true
    } else {
        currentExpandedIndex = anIndex
    }
    println(indexSet)
    myInfoTableView.reloadSections(indexSet ,withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Middle)
}
}
  //MARK:- TableView Delegate and DataSource Methods -
 extension MyInfoView: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return headerNamesArray!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    cellDetailsArray![headerNamesArray![section]];
    return cellDetailsArray![headerNamesArray![section]]!.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("InfoCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    var headerSection = indexPath.section
    cell.userTextField.placeholder = cellDetailsArray![headerNamesArray![headerSection]]![indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if isButtonTapped && currentExpandedIndex == indexPath.section {
        return 40.0
    }
    else {
        return 0.0
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TableHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil) [0] as! TableHeaderView
    headerView.headerButton.setTitle(headerNamesArray![section], forState: .Normal)
    headerView.applyViewStyle()
    headerView.headerButton.tag = section
    headerView.headerButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("headerButtonTapped:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    headerView.arrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: "sidearrow.png")
    if currentExpandedIndex == section {
        headerView.arrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: "downarrow.png")
    }
    return headerView
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40.0
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No You don't need to insert anything. Just update the variables of the data you want to display and reload the tableview.

e.g. in **Swift 3**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var sections = ["pizza", "deep dish pizza"]

var items = [["Margarita", "BBQ Chicken", "Pepperoni"], ["sausage", "meat lovers", "veggie lovers"]]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section]
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items[section].count
}
```

Then you can do this to update the tableview:

```
fun onClick(){
    sections.append("calzone")
    items[2].append(["sausage", "chicken pesto", "prawns", "mushrooms"])
    tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Disclaimer: You are probably working in Swift 2.2 if you are on Xcode 6 , but the functions are obviously similar, and the premise remains the same.

Comment: reloading the whole table view is bad practice.

Comment: @bibscy please feel free to submit a solution you feel answers this question more appropriately, but its 2 years since I answered this and I still stand by this code, method and practice.